Can I create a dynamic variable that gets a new value everytime for dvc.yaml
I'm aiming to incorporate a unique identifier into my dvc.yaml file every time I execute dvc repro. I'm using a Python script, generate_uuid.py, to generate a UUID and store it in a JSON file. Then, in my dvc.yaml, I've set up the first stage to run this Python script. However, in the subsequent stage, I need to use the output from the JSON file, which isn't created until after the first stage runs. This causes my program to fail during parsing. How can I resolve this issue?
My dvc.yaml looks like the following: uuid_var is in uuid.json. The uuid json file will only be created after generate_uuid stage
Stages: 
 generate_uuid:
    cmd: python generate_uuid.py
    deps:
      - generate_uuid.py
    outs:
      - uuid.json
 training:
    cmd: python train.py --run_name $(uuid_var)
    deps:
      - uuid.json
    vars:
      - uuid.json:uuid_var


Could you share the pipeline? That would help to see what the issue is. From the brief description. Second stage should depend on the JSON file (deps section in the dvc.yaml's stage) and it should prevent it from running until the first stage is done. Thus the second stage should always have a file to parse.

Could you please put into a code block in the question itself? Thanks.
